# arduino assembly transmit and receive

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

i have been trying to create a simple code in assembly that takes a character as input from the serial port and outputs the same character back. I have been able to get it to work but it seems like i cannot stop the output from writing the same character over and over. there should be a bit that i need to set/reset but cannot seem to figure it out. The code is below. i know i could have done it easily in C but i have been to mean to myself :).

```
;************************************
; serial.asm
;************************************

.nolist
.include "./m328Pdef.inc"
.list


.cseg

;
; Set up the Interrupt Vector at 0x0000
;
; We only use 1 interrupt in this program, the RESET
; interrupt.
;

.org 0x0000
    jmp reset       ; PC = 0x0000   RESET


;======================
; initialization

.org 0x0034
reset: 
    clr r1          ; set the SREG to 0
    out SREG, r1

    ldi r28, LOW(RAMEND)    ; init the stack pointer to point to RAMEND
    ldi r29, HIGH(RAMEND)
    out SPL, r28
    out SPH, r29

    rcall   USART_Init      ; initialize the serial communications
    sei             ; enable global interrupts
    rjmp    main

;=======================
; Initialize the USART
;
USART_Init:
    ; these values are for 9600 Baud with a 16MHz clock
    ldi r16, 103
    clr r17

    ; Set baud rate
    sts UBRR0H, r17
    sts UBRR0L, r16

    ; Enable receiver and transmitter
    ldi r16, (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0)
    sts UCSR0A, r16

    ; Enable receiver and transmitter
    ldi r16, (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0)
    sts UCSR0B, r16

    ; Set frame format: Async, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit
    ldi r16, 0b00001110
    sts UCSR0C, r16
    ret

;=======================
; send a byte over the serial wire
; byte to send is in r19

USART_Transmit:
    ; wait for empty transmit buffer
    lds r16, UCSR0A
    sbrs    r16, UDRE0
    rjmp    USART_Transmit

    ; Put data (r19) into buffer, sends the data
    sts UDR0, r17
    ret

USART_Receive:
    lds r16,UCSR0A          ; load UCSR0A into r16
    sbrs    r16,UDRE0           ; wait for empty transmit buffer
    rjmp    USART_Receive               ; repeat loop

    lds r17, UDR0       ; get received character
    rcall   USART_Transmit


    ret


delay: 
    ldi  r18, 41
    ldi  r19, 150
    ldi  r20, 128
L1: dec  r20
    brne L1
    dec  r19
    brne L1
    dec  r18
    brne L1

;======================
; Main body of program:

main:

loop:
    rcall   USART_Receive       ; send the character in r19 to the USART

    rcall delay 
    rjmp    loop            ; else go back and to reset the value in r19
```

Comment: Ummm why is your instruction `sts UDR0, r17` if you want to send `r19`? Also why isn't your receive waiting for available input instead of empty transmit buffer?

Comment: r19 is a bad comment, if you see i am receiving input character into r17 ( in USART_receive)  and putting it out in USART_Transmit. how do i check for available input? i thought an empty transmit buffer is an indication that data is ready to be received?

Comment: The MSB of `UCSRA0` is the "USART Receive Complete". You might want to wait on that.

Comment: Mr jester, the joke is on me :). That worked. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You are enabling global interrupts without a complete interrupt vector table. Why?